# Is it possible to customize some Google Map street colors to red or blue?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to change some of streets color to red or blue on a Google Map, like Google Maps navigation? Is it possible? I use ASP.net with JavaScript. I added my map:

```js
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.9, 30.6);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
    },
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
```

Comment: I'm guessing you would have to add a route and then change the colour of it, I don't think you would be able to change the colour of the streets on the map itself

Comment: Yes you're right. I can change the route color, but i want to change two different streets color. And these streets are not unified

Comment: Are you talking about Styled Maps? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sqvej/

Comment: What streets do you want to color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example using the directions service to highlight two routes, one red (#FF0000) and one blue (#0000FF).  You need to select the origin and destination parameters of the routes appropriately and might need to add waypoints if the chosen route doesn't follow the road you want.

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.9, 30.6);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
    },
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
  var directionsService1 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay1 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000"
    },
    preserveViewport: true,
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  directionsService1.route({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(36.95206, 30.636348),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(36.9058, 30.682199),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay1.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
  var directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay2 = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: "#0000FF"
    },
    preserveViewport: true,
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  directionsService2.route({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(36.899706, 30.763309),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(36.94513, 30.831226),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay2.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```